# How to parse this json with jq

Tags: json, mongodb, bash, jq

```
{ "inprog" : [ { "host" : "DESKTOP-LTB3QQ5:27017", "desc" : "conn25", "connectionId" : 25, "client" : "127.0.0.1:38354", "appName" : "MongoDB Shell", "clientMetadata" : { "application" : { "name" : "MongoDB Shell" }, "driver" : { "name" : "MongoDB Internal Client", "version" : "3.6.8" }, "os" : { "type" : "Linux", "name" : "Ubuntu", "architecture" : "x86_64", "version" : "20.04" } }, "active" : true, "currentOpTime" : "2021-03-16T11:01:14.599+0530", "opid" : 3135, "lsid" : { "id" : UUID("82088a94-16c2-4aa2-92d8-c557e74049a1"), "uid" : BinData(0,"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=") }, "secs_running" : NumberLong(0), "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(65), "op" : "command", "ns" : "admin.$cmd.aggregate", "command" : { "currentOp" : 1, "lsid" : { "id" : UUID("82088a94-16c2-4aa2-92d8-c557e74049a1") }, "$db" : "admin" }, "numYields" : 0, "locks" : { }, "waitingForLock" : false, "lockStats" : { } } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

command `cat mon.json | jq`

when I parse this with jq I get this error

`parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 493`

I think this is because "id": UUID("82088a94-16c2-4aa2-92d8-c557e74049a1")

Comment: As the message says, that's not valid JSON. `UUID(...)`, `BinData(...)`, `NumberLong(...)`, etc. are invalid.

Comment: The fragments `BinData(0,"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=")` and `NumberLong(...)` are also not valid JSON; also your line numbers etc do not match up. Going forward, see the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Also, tangentially, [the `cat` is useless.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: To answer your actual question, there is no way for a JSON parser to parse text which is not JSON. Probably request corrected output from whoever or whatever provided you with this data.

Comment: You would have to convert your data to JSON before being able to use jq with it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144236/how-to-convert-a-mongodb-document-to-json-object

Answer (score 2):

The logfile is in BSON format, however `jq` parses only JSON, see [JSON and BSON](https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson).

Obviously your files comes from `db.currentOp()`, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287020/save-output-of-a-mongo-command-to-a-variable-bash-script

Why do you try to run a shell script? You an do it all in mongo shell script (which is JavaScript). Could look similar to this:

```
db.currentOp().inprog.forEach(function (x) {
   if (x.op == "find" && x.secs_running > 5) {
      db.killOp(x.opid);
   }
})
```

Printing all commands would be similar to this:

```
db.currentOp().inprog.map(x => x.command)
```

I would say, it's time to learn [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp).

Comment: Yes, I would rather do it in javascript or python, but I am required to do it in shell script

Comment: That's really pointless. Use the shell script only to call the javascript, i.e. `mongo -u username -p password --quiet <your_javascript.js>` or use the `--eval` option, i.e.  `mongo -u username -p password --quiet --eval "db.currentOp().inprog.map(x => x.command)"`. It's no problem to put multiple commands into `eval` option.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use jq with your data, you will first have to convert it to (or render it as) JSON. This can be done in various ways, e.g. using `mongoexport`:

> mongoexport is a command-line tool that produces a JSON or CSV export of data stored in a MongoDB instance.

https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  Thought it was obvious. See update.